# Pytest: Parametrizing Non-Trivial Test Arguments

Tags: python, pytest

So I'm trying to create some tests in pytest for a function that uses Quantities from the pint library as inputs. I've read some documentation/tutorials on how to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize`, but the examples all seem to use literals as the parametrized arguments - I want to use Quantities. The way pint works is that I need to create a new unit registry using `u = UnitRegistry()` and then create the quantities using something like `3.0 * u.ft`. Is it possible to parametrize arguments that require some sort of setup logic? I assume this is doable using fixtures, but I can't figure out how to use the two features together.

Comment: You can just call functions (not fixtures) for your `parametrize` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of four ways to do this:

1. Create a module-level unit registry, then use `parametrize()` like normal:

   ```py
   u = pint.UnitRegistry()

   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
           "q1, q2", [
               (3 * u.ft, 4 * u.ft),
           ]
   )
   def test_my_func(q1, q2):
       ...
   ```

   This wouldn't work if you also want to parametrize the unit registry, but it seems like it'd work well for most things.  Generally it is good to avoid module-level variables, but in this case that's how the registry is designed to work.
2. Parametrize the test function with strings, then parse the strings into quantities in the test function:

   ```py
   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
           "q1, q2", [
               ("3 ft", "4 ft"),
           ]
   )
   def test_my_func(q1, q2):
       u = pint.UnitRegistry()
       q1, q2 = u(q1), u(q2)
   ```

   This approach is specific to the `pint` library, but not knowing anything else about your needs, it seems like the best solution to me.
3. Parametrize the test functions with lambda functions, then call those functions in the test function:

   ```py
   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
           "q1, q2", [
               (lambda u: 3 * u.ft, lambda u: 4 * u.ft),
           ]
   )
   def test_my_func(q1, q2):
       u = pint.UnitRegistry()
       q1, q2 = q1(u), q2(u)
   ```

   This is the the most flexible approach, although it's also the most verbose.
4. Parametrize the test function with strings containing snippets of python code, then `eval()`/`exec()` those snippets inside the test function:

   ```py
   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
           "q1, q2", [
               ("3 * u.ft", "4 * u.ft"),
           ]
   )
   def test_my_func(q1, q2):
       u = pint.UnitRegistry(),
       q1, q2 = eval(q1, locals()), eval(q2, locals())
   ```

   This is basically just a more succinct version of the `lambda` approach.  I think it works especially well if the parameters are being loaded from a file.